# how to Ctrl+A page and Input that into a string

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am making a puppeteer program were it checks Google Docs 
I want to be able to select all the text in the Google Docs and be able to make it into a string or a variable

I tried to Copy the text in the Google docs But didn't know where to go from there

```
await page2.keyboard.down('Control');
await page2.keyboard.press('KeyA');
await page2.keyboard.press('KeyC');
await page2.keyboard.up('Control');
```

I don't know where to go from here

Comment: Maybe, a better approach would be to use the root element (`body` for example) and take it's innerHTML. What do you want to do with this string? I think this approach is not very reliable.

Comment: on google docs, I tried Everything they all return null. So when I tried to ctrl-A and C then Paste into a notebook it worked I just have to make puppeteer do the same. And thank you so much for replying

Comment: There are some limitations with what you're trying to accomplish, read [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1313) and let us know (if and) how you resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft')
    await page.keyboard.press('KeyA')
    await page.keyboard.press('KeyC');
    await page.keyboard.up('ControlLeft')
```